# Complex variable solving: 1000 = 500x^2 - 500x

Tags: javascript, algebra

I'm using javascript and would like to know how to solve this algebraic expression.

Original Equation:

```
1000 = 500x^2 - 500x
```

This is the equation I want to solve.
I tried simplifying it to get the Xs on the same side of the equation
but ended up with this.

```
1000 = 500x(x - 1)
1000/500 = x^2 - x
sqrt(1000/500 + x) = x
```

If I solve it other ways, I would get 2 answers for one variable. `x = 2, -1`
The method above seemed to be the best way to just get 2 out from the equation but I do not know how to go about the logic for solving it in code.

Now the Xs are on two different sides of the equation.
This is what I came up with code but the output is NaN.

```
var level = Number(Math.floor(Math.sqrt((1000/500) + level)));
```

of course this poses a problem because i need to find level with the value of level.

How would I go about solving this equation in code?

---

More specifically, the 1000 is just a place holder value.

```
var xp = Number(getProp('xp'));
var level = Number(Math.floor(Math.sqrt((xp/500) + level)));
```

My program is supposed to find what level you are when you have what amount of xp.

`var xp` gets the amount of xp that you currently have.

At 1000 xp, you become level 2.
`Number(getProp('xp')` is there because I am doing this in google sheets.

Comment: A better simplification for that equation would be: `2 = x(x - 1)` or `x(x - 1) = 2`.

Comment: Just use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula to solve your quadratic equation. `500x^2 - 500x - 1000 = 0`, `a=500`, `b=-500`, `c=-1000`. Remember that a quadratic equation can have two solutions (your example gives `x1=2`, `x2=-1`).

Comment: An alternative simplification might be (x - 2)(x + 1) = 0

Comment: Just to be sure, are you setting `level` to any value before using it? you cant declare a value, and use its value on declaration: `var level = level;` is not a correct semantic, and a NaN. `var level = 0; level = level + 2;` is correct.

Comment: @Bonatti I figured that is why I was getting an output of NaN.

Comment: @forrert How do I determine which value the variable will be set to? I want to go with the quadratic formula but how do I distinguish the output of just 2?

Comment: I'm not 100% I understand your problem correctly... Assuming you want to find the level given an amount of experience and you want to use the formula you mentioned, I would suggest this formula: `function getLevel(xp) { var b = -500, a = 500; return (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4 * a * (-xp)))/ (2*a);}`. The parameters `a` and `b` are constants in your case, and `c = -xp`, the returned value will be your level.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you. I think that is what I want. We will see.

Comment: @forrert Thank you. I was able to get the correct answer (with a bit of modification).

Answer (score 0):

[As per documentation:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt)

> Description
>
> If the value of x is negative, Math.sqrt() returns NaN.
>
> Because sqrt() is a static method of Math, you always use it as Math.sqrt(), rather than as a method of a Math object you created (Math is not a constructor).

Either use the [absolute value (modulo)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) of your value, or ensure that is always positive.

Also, before using any variable in JavaScript, ensure that its type is the expected one, or that it exists.

```
function getLevel(xp){
   if(typeof xp === 'number') {
      return Math.sqrt(Math.abs(xp/500));
   } else {
      return -1; // this is an error....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The answer came from @forret:

```
function getLevel(xp) 
{ 
  var b = -500, a = 500; 
  return (-b + Math.sqrt(b*b - >4 * a * (-xp)))/ (2*a);
}
```

It just uses the quadratic formula.